# Why can't I start a great holy war

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am the Fylkir (reformed norse version of the pope) and would very much like to know why I cannot start another holy war.

I am playing as Empire of Britannia. I have all the holy sites. The year is over 1100 and both the Muslims and the Catholics have called crusades before. The norse faith has over 100% moral authority. I have even started (and won) 4 great holy wars earlier, last one being about 30 years ago.

Why can't I start a holy war now?

Comment: The question is confusing. Only the Catholic pope can call a crusade. The head of the Norse faith can call a Great Holy War. Do you have any moral authority? You need at least 5% to call a Great Holy War.

Comment: @Nix I have edited the question to make it less confusing

Comment: @PenguinAgen Have you had one in past 10 years? IIRC you can call it every 10 years.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka No, last one was about 30 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double check the time since the last Great Holy War ended. I believe the cooldown for the Great Holy War CB is 30 years from the end of your last Great Holy War.

Comment: A little searching seems to confirm the [30 year cool down](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?695178-What-is-the-precise-condition-for-quot-great-holy-war-quot-I-m-not-meaning-about-AD-1100)